# What are the differences (if any) between classical and modern predicativity

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-logic

I am researching Predicativity and I've encounterd defenition for classical predicativity and for modern predicativity but I can't understand the differences between them. 
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the definitions you've encountered.